# Magento 2.4 - Delete website/store/store_view programmatically

Tags: multistore, magento2.4, multi-website

I know you can delete the website/store/store_view via the admin panel, however, can you remove those programmatically? Via a PHP script, custom module or CLI?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code:

```
<?php
namespace Name\Module\Model;
class Delete
{
    private $storeRepository;
    private $websiteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository $storeRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository $websiteRepository
    ){
        $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
        $this->websiteRepository = $websiteRepository;
    }

    protected function delete(){
        //Delete Store
        $storeCode = 'en';
        $store = $this->storeRepository->get($storeCode);
        $store->delete();

        //Delete Websites
        $websiteCode = 'code';
        $website = $this->websiteRepository->get($websiteCode);
        $website->getResource()->delete($website);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I added the patch patches/composer/ImportBehaviorAddUpdate.php to edit the file vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php like this:

```
index 7ea5rf..8852963 123321
--- a/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php
@@ -2323,7 +2323,7 @@
                     $websitesData[] = ['product_id' => $productId, 'website_id' => $websiteId];
                 }
             }
-            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND != $this->getBehavior()) {
+            if (Import::BEHAVIOR_ADD_UPDATE != $this->getBehavior()) {
                 $this->_connection->delete(
                     $tableName,
                     $this->_connection->quoteInto('product_id IN (?)', $delProductId)
```

then add to composer.json in the root of your magento : Add the extra section (if you dont have one already) :

```
{
   "extra": {
        "magento/module-catalog-import-export": {
                "Change the behavior of import for websites savings": "patches/composer/ImportBehaviorAddUpdate.patch"
            }
    }
}
```

Lastly run composer update and bin/magento setup:di:compile.

Hope it helps